# How to check a newly created user in Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i used the firebase email and password authentication android technique to create a new user in my project. Everything seems to be working fine but after creating a new user, i checked the console to see if the user's email and password will be displayed. I don't know where it has been stored.

Thanks

Comment: go to the console> authentication email will be stored there

Comment: @PeterHaddad the passwords are not showing, where do i access them?

Comment: Firebase is BAAS (backend as a service) all data/files everything is stored in google cloud , so the passwords are stored there. You cannot see the passwords for security reasons

Comment: alright thank you. Is there a way to access it in your java code? @PeterHaddad

Comment: yes when the user enters the password in edittext do this `String password=edittext.getText().toString()`

Comment: oh that's true, thanks once more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Firebase -> Click on your project -> Click on develop tab on the left and you can see Authentication button -> Click on Authentication and it will open up a table as shown in the screenshot
[image]

the identifier field shows the email address

Comment: thanks @ajayreddy The passwords are not showing though, where do i access that?